# How to load rosdil_fault_generators through terminal?

Tags: ros2

After going through the tutorials up to the intermediate in Humble, I switched to Iron, thinking I would review the tutorials. Unfortunately, while building the `tutorial_interfaces`, I received the following error:

```
could not find a package configuration file provided by "rosdil_default_generators" with any of the following names:
rosdil_default_generatorsConfig.cmake
rosdil_default_generators-config.cmake
```

Please note that I had no problems on Humble. The command `ros2 pkg list` shows folllwing information:

```
$ ros2 pkg list
rosdil_generator_c, rosdil_generator_cpp, rosdil_generator_py, rosdil_generator_type_description
```

How to load `rosdil_fault_generators` through terminal?